# Ubuntu 18.04 Change pimary Monitor

Tags: 18.04, multiple-monitors

In earlier versions ob Ubuntu I could easily change my primary Monitor.

This morning out of a sudden my external Display is the primary monitor.
How to change this?

[image]

( I do not see any option via Settings -> Devices -> Displays )

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6TDR.gif

Comment: @PRATAP Thx - I like the animated picture so I added it to the other answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just click on the Display-name (Ancor Communications ...)  to the right of "Primary Display" :)

[image: enter link description here]